# How can we prove that "extract almost minimum" operation in a priority queue cannot be done in o(log n)?

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, priority-queues

Suppose we want to create a priority queue with 2 operations: insert and extract almost min. Extract almost min operation selects either the first minimum or a second minimum item from the structure randomly, removes that item from the structure and outputs that item.

How can we prove that both of these operations cannot be done in $o(\log n)$?.

My approach: If you could prove that you can sort a list with a comparison based algorithm in $O(n)$ you could prove it by contradiction.

But to sort a list we will need $n$ calls of extract almost min and with $o(log n)$ time which would be $o(n\log n) +$ swaps to fix the elements that are 2nd largest. Would that be enough to prove this contradiction that this is faster than $O(\log n)$?

Or is there a way to sort it in $O(n)$ or prove this?

Comment: There is no way to sort in $O(n)$ unless, for example, extract almost min can be done in $O(1)$.

Comment: You need to bound the number of swaps required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have thought is not a bad start. However, more arguments are needed to establish the proposition.

---

Given $n$ items, we can insert all of them into the priority queue and then extract almost min $n$ times to obtain a list of all items. Unfortunately, the obtained list is not sorted unless the minimum is extracted every time.

##### A mix of heapsort and insertion sort

Here is the adjusted procedure such that the obtained list right before the next extraction is sorted always.

1. Insert all $n$ items into a priority queue $pq$.
2. Initialize an empty list $answer$.
3. While $pq$ is not empty:

   1. Extract almost min to get an "almost minimum" $\alpha$.
   2. Append $\alpha$ to $answer$.
   3. While $\alpha$ is smaller than the item right before it, swap the two.
4. Return $answer$, which is a sorted list of the given $n$ items.

The outer step 3 is just insertion sort but with the next item provided by "extract almost min" operation on $pq$. It is much faster than usual insertion sort, since an item will not be moved any more after it has been moved backwards once as "the item right before" some "$\alpha$". This fact will be proved below in detail.

##### The number of swaps and comparisons at step 3.3

Suppose we executed the procedure. Consider an item $\beta$ in $answer$ that was swapped with some $\alpha$ at some moment when step 3.3 was executed. That means $\alpha$ was extracted later than $\beta$ and $\alpha$ is smaller than $\beta$.

Consider the moment when $\beta$ was output by "extract almost min" on $pq$. Every item in $pq$ other than the minimum was not smaller than $\beta$. Hence, $\alpha$ must be that minimum.

So the same $\beta$ can be swapped with one $\alpha$ only. The swap between the same pair of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ cannot happen more than once, since $\alpha$ moves to the front always and $\beta$ moves to the back always. Hence at most $n-1$ swaps are made at step 3.3 during the whole execution of the procedure.

For each execution of the while loop of step 3.3, every comparison is followed by a swap except the last comparison. So the number of comparisons at step 3.3 during the whole execution of the procedure is $n-1$  more than the number of swaps, i.e., at most $2(n-1)$.

##### Conclusion

Towards a contradiction assume both insertion and extraction can be done in $o(\log n)$ time.

The running time of the procedure above is $$o(n\log n)+o(n\log n)+ O(n)+ O(n) + O(n)=o(n\log n).$$

Note that both big $O$-notation and little $O$-natation are used.
However, it is known there is no comparison sort that uses $o(n\log n)$ comparisons. This contradiction means it is not true that both insertion and extraction can be done in $o(\log n)$.

##### An exercise

Prove the same proposition if "almost min" is defined as any one of the $m$ minimum items for some constant $m$ instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's not enough yet, because you haven't described how to sort in $o(n \log n)$ time -- in particular, you haven't described how to do the swaps in $o(n \log n)$ time.  But yes, if you could figure out how to do that, then that *would* be enough.